# Export xml result in txt file in SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, file, text-files

I was wondering if someone can help me...I have a stored procedure that returns an xml result. I need to save this result in a text file in the following format:

CLEAR

CHIAVE REG

VEND REP=1,qty=1,PRICE=130,DES='coffee'

CHIU TEND=1

qty, price and description comes from the xml result.
Is this possible? Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 0):

You could build a varchar string and save it to a text file at the end.  The limitation here though is the maximum varchar value (8000).

I've used this sproc to do it;

```
alter PROCEDURE spWriteStringToFile
 (
@String Varchar(max), --8000 in SQL Server 2000
@Path VARCHAR(255),
@Filename VARCHAR(100)

--
)
AS
DECLARE  @objFileSystem int
        ,@objTextStream int,
        @objErrorObject int,
        @strErrorMessage Varchar(1000),
        @Command varchar(1000),
        @hr int,
        @fileAndPath varchar(80)

set nocount on

select @strErrorMessage='opening the File System Object'
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @objFileSystem OUT

Select @FileAndPath=@path+'\'+@filename
if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objFileSystem , @strErrorMessage='Creating file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod   @objFileSystem   , 'CreateTextFile'
    , @objTextStream OUT, @FileAndPath,2,True

if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, 
    @strErrorMessage='writing to the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Write', Null, @String

if @HR=0 Select @objErrorObject=@objTextStream, @strErrorMessage='closing the file "'+@FileAndPath+'"'
if @HR=0 execute @hr = sp_OAMethod  @objTextStream, 'Close'

if @hr<>0
    begin
    Declare 
        @Source varchar(255),
        @Description Varchar(255),
        @Helpfile Varchar(255),
        @HelpID int

    EXECUTE sp_OAGetErrorInfo  @objErrorObject, 
        @source output,@Description output,@Helpfile output,@HelpID output
    Select @strErrorMessage='Error whilst '
            +coalesce(@strErrorMessage,'doing something')
            +', '+coalesce(@Description,'')
    raiserror (@strErrorMessage,16,1)
    end
EXECUTE  sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
EXECUTE sp_OADestroy @objTextStream
```